# CDbException CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i work on a php mysql project on yii framework .but it give following error-

CDbException

CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty.

i am new on php .please help me what i do for fixing this problem.

i added my main.php

```
 <?php
// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'College Management System',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.extensions.jtogglecolumn.*',

        'application.extensions.AjaxList.AjaxList',
        'application.components.*',

        'application.modules.rights.*',
        'application.modules.rights.components.*',

         'application.modules.notification.models.*',
        //'application.modules.hrms.components.*',
        'application.modules.mailbox.*',
        'application.modules.mailbox.models.*',
        //'application.modules.importation.models.*',
        'application.extensions.html2pdf.*',
        'application.extensions.crontab.*',

    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'secure',
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                    'ext.gii-extended',
                ),
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1','192.168.0.163'),
        ),
        'notification',
        'webservice',
        'rights'=>array(
            'install'=>false,
            'superuserName'=>'SuperAdmin',
            'authenticatedName'=>'Authenticated',
            'userIdColumn'=>'user_id',
            'userNameColumn'=>'user_organization_email_id',
            'userTypeColumn'=>'user_type',
            'enableBizRule'=>true,
            'enableBizRuleData'=>false,
            'displayDescription'=>true,
            'flashSuccessKey'=>'RightsSuccess',
            'flashErrorKey'=>'RightsError',
            'baseUrl'=>'/rights',
            'layout'=>'rights.views.layouts.main',
            'appLayout'=>'application.views.layouts.main',
            'cssFile'=>'rights.css',
            'debug'=>false,
            ),

        'dashboard' => array(
          'debug' => true,
          'portlets' => array(
        'Time_Table' => array('class' => 'Time_Table', 'visible' => true, 'weight' => 1),
        'Attendance' => array('class' => 'Attendance', 'visible' => true, 'weight' => 2),       
        'Calendar' => array('class' => 'Calendar', 'visible' => true, 'weight' => 4),
        'Important_notice' => array('class' => 'Important_notice', 'visible' => true, 'weight' => 5), 
        'GTU_Notice' => array('class' => 'GTUNotice', 'visible' => true, 'weight' => 6), 
          ),

        ),

    'mailbox'=>
            array(  
            'userClass' => 'User',
          //  'userIdColumn' => 'id',
            'userIdColumn' => 'user_id',
            'usernameColumn' => 'user_organization_email_id',
            //'usernameColumn' => 'username',
            //'superuserColumn'=>'user_type',
           // 'pageSize' => 50,
            'newsUserId' => 'admin@rudrasoftech.com',
              ),

    'wdcalendar'    => //array( 'admin' => 'install' ),
            array( 
                'embed'=>true,
                                'wd_options' => array(  
                                    'view' => 'month',
                                   // 'readonly' => 'JS:true' // execute JS
                                ) 
                           ),


    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'class'=>'RWebUser',
        ),

        'phpThumb'=>array(
            'class'=>'ext.EPhpThumb.EPhpThumb',

        ),

        'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'RDbAuthManager',
        ),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),

        /*'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(


             'gii'=>'gii',
                 'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
                 'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',

            //'<controller:(c1|c2|c3|gii)/>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',   
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',

            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', 

                         array('webservice/api/login', 'pattern'=>'webservice/api/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),                
             array('webservice/api/list', 'pattern'=>'webservice/api/<model:\w+>/<uid:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
             array('webservice/api/view', 'pattern'=>'webservice/api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<uid:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
             array('webservice/api/update', 'pattern'=>'webservice/api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
             array('webservice/api/delete', 'pattern'=>'webservice/api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
             array('webservice/api/create', 'pattern'=>'webservice/api/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),               


            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',


            ),
            'showScriptName'=>false,
        ),
        /*
        /*'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),*/
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database



/*

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hansaba_hrms_test',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'ubuntu',
            'charset' => 'utf8',    
            'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',        

        ),
*/      'db'=>require('db.php'),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
                    'errorAction'=>'site/error',
                ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',

                ),
//              array(
//                  'class'=>'CEmailLogRoute',
//                  'levels'=>'error, warning',
//                  'emails'=>'karmraj@rudrasoftech.com',
//              ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
               // this is used in contact page
               'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
               'pageSize'=>25,
               'webRoot' => dirname(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..')
       ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, you didn't set database connection string in your `protected/config/main.php` file.

you have to set like

```
'db'=>array(

            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'pass',           
            .
            .
            .
        ),
```

Comment: sir i add my main.php ..please tell me now??

Comment: In you config, you are including a file. So you have to add code from db.php in question